Formation energy AXO3 - free atoms or elemental solids?
I am trying to calculate the formation energy of a perovskite compound with, say, $\ce{AXO3}$-structure. The formation energy is given as
$E_\mathrm{form}=E_\mathrm{\ce{AXO3}}-\sum_in_iE_i$
with $i$ running over the constituents and $n_i$ the relative weight in the compound, i.e. $n_\mathrm{X}=1$ or $n_\mathrm{O}=3$.
Now when I calculate the reference energies of the constituents, I have seen multiple approaches in the literature. For example for oxygen, some calculate the energy of a free oxygen atom in a large supercell. Others take the $T\approx0\,\mathrm{K}$ structure which is of the spacegroup C 1 2/m 1. Again others use the energy of an oxygen molecule $\ce{O2}$. I could however not find and/or grasp which choice is correct when judging the stability of a structure through $E_\mathrm{form}$.
So my question is: Which approach is correct and what is the reasoning we choose one over the other?

These may help you: link, link, link.

@Camps Thanks for the links; actually these were what confused me: First one suggests using the bulk as a reference when $n_i$ becomes large; regardless I have found examples in literature where the atomic energy was used instead even though $n_i$ was not small. That is why I was hoping for some more information over the reasoning when to choose what

It only depends on what you want to look at.  An atomic energy reference should provide the same insights on relative stability of things in general, however most people care about things on the convex hull of a phase diagram.  By that logic, a better reference is the most stable single element bulk phase as it would be "on the hull" naturally.
I would generally suggest using the standard state of an element, not its atomic reference. There may be cases where this doesn't work well (O$_2$ comes to mind as its poorly described by DFT), but I think most people would naturally expect your formation energies to be relative to bulk phase.  As long as you report your reference state, you can use whatever reference you would like though if there is something more suitable for you.

Thanks, that makes sense. One clarification: When you say "should provide the same insights on relative stability", can the sign of the formation energy change depending on which reference state we use? I would intuitively assume that there could be a difference in the sign if $E_\mathrm{form}$ is small and we compare solid oxygen vs. $\ce{O2}$ as a reference

Sure the sign can change, the sign just indicates if the reference state is more stable (can you form it and avoid decomposition thermodynanically)
